# Length of string using double pointers in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to get the length of a string using **double pointers** but for some reason its not displaying correctly. Some explanation would be greatly appreciated. I feel like i'm missing something simple here.

(I am aware this can be done with a single pointer.)

```
#include <stdio.h>

void find_length(char**);

int main() {
    char* p = "this a message";
    char** k = &p;
    find_length(k);
    return 0;

}

void find_length(char **k) {
    while (*k != '\0') {
        printf("%c", *k);
        k++;
    }

}
```

Comment: Take a piece of paper. Draw boxes to represent the buffer `p` points to, and `p` itself. Now answer the following question: what is the value of the expressions `k`, `*k` and `**k`. Now do `k++` in your head and repeat the exercise. If you need concrete addresses, assume `p=1000` and `k=50`.

Comment: Please compile with the warnings enabled (or just read them). They should be pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: Why are you comparing a pointer to a character constant?  `*k` has type `char *`, right?  It's a pointer.  You compare it to `NULL`, not `'\0'`.  Also, you can't use `%c` with a pointer.  It needs a character value.  If you want a useless second `*`, then you need to add it everywhere, not just in the argument declaration.

Comment: A doouble pointer is a pointer to a pointer. That is all you need to know. Read your code again and ask for each `* ` you see "What is that pointing to?". This is wrong `*k != '\0'` and this `k++`.

Comment: I roughly remember that Kernigan was asked why they have chosen the same `*` for declaration _and_ dereferencing in expressions which might be confusing. The answer was (roughly) that they liked the idea that a variable declared as `T **a` needs and expression `**a` to resolve a pointer to its contents of type `T` (which is easy to remember).

Comment: I remembered wrong: It's found in the book [The Development of the C Language](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/chist.html) but the author was the other father of C - Dennis Ritchie. The mentioned part is found searching for the subject "Embryonic C".

Comment: Solution: don't use pointer to pointer. That's the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Ask yourself: When you have a pointer to `T` and you indirect through that pointer what do you get?

> You get `T`

Now, ask yourself: When `T` is `char`, the pointer in question is `char*` i.e. pointer to char; what do you get when you indirect through that?

> You get `char`

Now, ask yourself: When `T` is `char*`, the pointer in question is `char**` i.e. pointer to pointer to char; what do you get when you indirect through that?

> You get `char*`

Now, ask yourself: What is the type of `'\0'`

> It is `char`.
>
>  Does it make sense to compare `char*` with `char`? No, it does not. Now, you have a `char*`, so how could you get a `char` out of it? By indirecting through it of course.
>
>  Another problem is that you are incrementing `k`. Incrementing a pointer is allowed when it points to element of an array. Does `k` point to an array of pointers? It does not. There is only one `char*` being pointed at. If you want to iterate through the array pointed by `*k`, then you need to increment `*k` (or a copy of it).

Answer (score 1):

- k is pointer to pointer to char
- *k is a pointer to char
- **k is a char

So when you check for `*k != '\0'` you check that the pointer to cahr is different from zero, not if the char is different from the null terminator in the string.

When you do the k++ you increase the pointer to pointer to point at the next pointer to char.

Try this instead.

```
void find_length(char **k) {
    char *kk = *k; // temp.
    while (*kk != '\0') {
        printf("%c", *kk);
        kk++;
    }    
}
```

Comment: as it doesnt return or store the length, perhaps `print_string` would be a better name ;)

Comment: @idclev463035818 the 2 big problems in computer science is naming, cache invalidation and off-by-one error. I'd leave it as an exercise to the OP.

Comment: @idclev463035818 `print_string_char_by_char`, `print_string` would be `printf("%s", *k)` :)

Comment: Not precise enough. I propose: `print_string_char_by_char_through_a_pointer_ಠ_ಠ`

Comment: I had considered print_string_char_by_char_through_a_pointer_to_pointer_to_char_ಠ_ಠ